# A problem on the sum of the reciprocals of two derivatives

Tags: analysis

If $f(x)$ is continuous in the closed interval $[a,b]$ and differentiable in the open interval $a<x<b$, and if $f(a)=a$, $f(b)=b$, prove there exist points $x_1$ and $x_2$ with $a<x_1<x_2<b$ for which the following equation is true: $1/f'(x_1)+1/f'(x_2)=2$.

Comment: What are your thoughts on this problem?

Comment: I am stuck...it is supposedly an exercise on the mean value theorem in the Advanced Calculus book by A.E.Taylor.

Comment: If the curve y=f(x) crosses the line y=x between x=a and x=b, then  the MVT shows that there are two points x_1 and x_2 where f'=1 and the problem is trivial.  The interesting case is where there is only ONE point where f'=1...and I am stuck.

Comment: Or, more simply, if f'=1 in two such points, for whatever reason, the problem is trivial.

Comment: Is the image of $f$ the interval $[a,b]$ also, or the problem doesn't mention this?

Comment: I've given the complete statement of the problem.  I've looked at parabolic examples like y=x(2-x) for a=0 and b=1, but to no avail.

Answer (score 3):

Since $f(x)$ is continuous in the closed interval $[a,b]$ $\exists c\in (a,b)$ s.t $f(c)=\frac{f(a)+f(b)}{2}=\frac{a+b}{2}$ by intermediate value theorem.

Then by mean value theorem,

$\exists x_1\in (a,c)$s.t. $f'(x_1)=\frac{\frac{a+b}{2}-f(a)}{c-a}=\frac{\frac{a+b}{2}-a}{c-a}=\frac{b-a}{2(c-a)}$

$\exists x_2\in (c,b)$s.t. $f'(x_2)=\frac{f(b)-\frac{a+b}{2}}{b-c}=\frac{b-\frac{a+b}{2}}{b-c}=\frac{b-a}{2(b-c)}$

Hence  $1/f'(x_1)+1/f'(x_2)=2$.

Comment: Very elegant.  Thank you very much, John ZHANG...

Comment: I never would have thought of using the intermediate value theorem that way...very nice.

Comment: @mark I am glad it helps.